# PHP If function does not work

Tags: php, if-statement

i am new to this PHP and would like some suggestion why my calculation does not work.

```
$income = number_format($_POST[income], 2);
$year = $_POST[year];
if ($income >= 0 && $income <= 18200){ 
    $taxo = number_format(0,2);}
elseif ($income >= 18201 && $income <= 37000){
    $taxo = number_format($income * 0.19 ,2);
}
```

and somewhere down in my HTML file

```
tax on income
$
echo $taxo;
```

However when i run the file, $taxo is alwasy 0 (?) .can anyone please advise where i got it wrong?

Thanks in advance

Albert

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: If echo shows up in HTML, you aren't parsing PHP on a server.

Comment: Are you able to `echo "Hello World";`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number_format()` returns a string, which you're trying to do integer comparisons on. e.g.

```
$income = '12345678';
$income = number_Format($income, 2); // 12,345,678.00

if ('12,345,678.00' >= 0) && ('12,345,678.00' <= 18200)
```

PHP will convert your string **BACK** to an integer, and you end up doing

```
if (12 >= 0) && (12 <= 18200)
```

`number_format()` is useful for human-readable output. It is utterly USELESS when you're doing internal-only comparisons, because you're taking what should be apples-to-apples comparisons, and turning them into oranges-to-apples.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$_POST[income]` with `$_POST['income']`  and `$_POST[year]` with `$_POST['year']`

Comment: Good advice, but PHP would politely treat them as unquoted strings anyways, at the cost of a warning.

Comment: @user3211379, Marc has given you a very clear explanation of it.